# Core Data addObject one-to-many relationShip

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, nsset

I have tried to add objects to my core data model. But, when I try to display them, they are not there. I am using a Category as a Helper.

```
+ (Project *)createProjectWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dic inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {

    Project *project = nil;

    // Build a fetch request to see if we can find this Flickr photo in the database.
    // The "unique" attribute in Photo is Flickr's "id" which is guaranteed by Flickr to be unique.

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Project"];
    request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES]];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title = %@", [dic[kTagProjectTitle]description]];

    // Execute the fetch

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *matches = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    // Check what happened in the fetch

    if (!matches || ([matches count] > 1)) {  // nil means fetch failed; more than one impossible (unique!)
        // handle error
    } else if (![matches count]) { // none found, so let's create a Photo for that Flickr photo
        project = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Project" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        NSLog(@"Encontrado Primera vez");

        project.projectId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[dic valueForKey:kTagProjectId] intValue]];
        project.title = [dic valueForKey:kTagProjectTitle];
        project.estimatedPrice = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[dic valueForKey:kTagProjectEstimatedPrice] floatValue]];
        NSMutableArray *tags = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        tags = [dic objectForKey:kTagProjectsTags];

        NSMutableSet *tagSet = [[NSMutableSet alloc]init];
        for (NSDictionary * tagDic in tags){
            NSString *tagName = [tagDic objectForKey:kTagProjectTagName];
            Tag *tag = [Tag insertTagName:tagName inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
            [project addTagsObject:tag];
        }

       // [project addTags:tagSet];
```

I have tried using a NSMutableSet with addObject:(NSSet *tag) , and also with addTagObject and I have the same output in NSLog.

```
            for( Tag *tag in project.tags){
                NSLog(@"TAG TITLES %@", tag.name);  
            }
       2013-09-30 23:03:36.003 Prototype[28959:c07] TAG TITLES iOS
       2013-09-30 23:03:36.004 Prototype[28959:c07] TAG TITLES Windows Phone
    }
```

Then, when I try to display them in the cell. I have a new NSLog and this is the output. Why in the firs NSLog I can see them and not in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   Project *project = (Project *)[self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   NSLog(@"TITLE %@", project.tags);
}
```

OUTPUT

```
 TITLE Relationship 'tags' on managed object (0x7c60ba0) <Project: 0x7c60ba0> (entity: Project; id: 0x7c60be0 <x-coredata:///Project/tE9F74F99-04BC-43CC-BD68-F435712B3B3C9> ; data: {

    estimatedPrice = 1999;
    projectId = 418;
    tags =     (
    );
    title = "Aplicaci\U00f3n IOS";
    "yp_desc" = nil;
}) with objects {(
)}

}
```

Comment: Is `[Tag insertTagName:tagName inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];` calling `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:`?

Comment: Yes, `[Tag insertTagName:tagName inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];` is almost the same method as [Project create..... but obviusly changing variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you didn't save context after adding tags.

Comment: Saving the context after add the tags object. I get this output: " tags =  <relationship fault: 0x7c73f50 'tags'>

Comment: It's OK. It means just data isn't actually fetched from DB - it will be fetched after you access some properties on object. Setup your cell now, all will work fine

Comment: I have put this in the NSLog in cellForRowAtIndexPath: `int i = 0;
        for( Tag *tag in project.tags){
            NSString *tagName = tag.name;
            NSLog(@"i value = %d", i);
            NSLog(@"TITLE %@", tagName);
           
        }` and there is no output, what means that I don't have any tag in my context.

Comment: 1) You overwrite project.tags somewhere. 2) You remove `Tag` objects somewhere. Also, you can check in debug where exactly `tags` property gets cleared

Comment: it is weird. I use this array for my rows `- (void)refreshData:(NSDictionary *)newData {
    managedObjectContext = [YPDataSingleton context];
    for (NSDictionary *projectDic in newData) {
        [data addObject:[Project createProjectWithDictionary: projectDic inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];
    }
  
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}` and also this after get Tags from service to core data`    
        [project addTags:tagSet];
        [ managedObjectContext save:nil]; `

Comment: Try to find out in debug, where the `tags` are gone. I can't give you an answer with existing amount of information. Everything seems OK

Comment: Ok, I am doing it, but one question. I am using a singleton to manage all the persistentStore  and the context. When do I have to save the context exactly? after each insert? or just at the end?

Comment: You should save context when your coredata writing transaction seems to be finished. For example, if you received 2 project objects with 8 tags from remote server you may save context after creating all objects, not after each insert. However, if you have done simple property change on NSManagedObject, you have to save context for your changes get commited to persistent store. In general, it's question of app's logic and performance - context's save after each insertion will significantly decrease application's performance. However, unsaved changes in context will be lost after closing the app

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you that you use the Magical Record framework (https://github.com/magicalpanda/magicalrecord), it makes too much easier Core Data management!

In the other hand if you want keep on without it I will try changing:

```
 + (Project *)createProjectWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dic inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {

    Project *project = nil;

    // Build a fetch request to see if we can find this Flickr photo in the database.
    // The "unique" attribute in Photo is Flickr's "id" which is guaranteed by Flickr to be unique.

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Project"];
    request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES]];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title = %@", [dic[kTagProjectTitle]description]];

    // Execute the fetch

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *matches = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    // Check what happened in the fetch

    if (!matches || ([matches count] > 1)) {  // nil means fetch failed; more than one impossible (unique!)
        // handle error
    } else if (![matches count]) { // none found, so let's create a Photo for that Flickr photo
        project = [matches lastObject];
        NSLog(@"Encontrado Primera vez");

        //Makes that only if you want to rehydrate your saved object. At other way I am not sure what yo want to do here :S
        project.projectId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[dic valueForKey:kTagProjectId] intValue]];
        project.title = [dic valueForKey:kTagProjectTitle];
        project.estimatedPrice = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[dic valueForKey:kTagProjectEstimatedPrice] floatValue]];
        NSMutableArray *tags = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        tags = [dic objectForKey:kTagProjectsTags];

        for (NSDictionary * tagDic in tags){
            NSString *tagName = [tagDic objectForKey:kTagProjectTagName];
            Tag *tag = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Tag" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
            //TODO: populate tag object using tagDic
            [project addTagsObject:tag];
        }
```

And remember to make the fetch in the same context if you haven't saved the current context ;)